# Messaging App MySQL Database Design

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating a messaging app and having trouble coming up with a database design that is scalable.

I found the following database design online but have a couple of questions about it.

In yellow, you will see the tables that I will be using

[image]

I got it from this website https://github.com/yoosuf/Messenger

My questions are:

- I don't see any way of tracking unread messages. Should I add a table called `unread_conversations` in which everytime a user sends a message, a record is inserted into unread_conversations with the `conversation_id` and the `user_id` of every participant of the conversation?
- When I fetch a users conversations, the query will be

  `select (whatever columns I need) 
  from conversations
  inner join messages on messages.id = conversations.last_message_id
  where user_id = {user_id}
  AND conversations.id not in (
  select conversation_id from deleted_conversations where user_id = {user_id}
  )
  ORDER by conversations.update_at DESC
  LIMIT 50`

(I will store the last message id in the `conversations` table in order to show a preview)

My main concern is that as the database scales, that all of these joins because of all of the tables will not make this a scalable design.

Although from a design perspective, it feels good.

Thoughts?